# How do we can get the rectangular frame of a segment in segmented control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Assume that I have an UI like the one below. I would like to get the first segment's frame to make it the spotlight to other views. How can I get the **frame** of the control, in a particular way with Obj-C? How to convert it to coordinate system of another view? 
I've try

```
CGRect rect=_segmentedControl.frame;
rect=[superview convertRect:rect toView:_anotherView];
```

but it didn't work.
I'm trying to use this library: https://github.com/praagyajoshi/WVWalkthroughView to make a onboarding experience for first-time user.
I'm new in here so I can not post the image directly here the image, sorry for this inconvenient.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the frame of the control you will need to check the subviews for your segmented control

**for Swift**

```
let rect = _segmentedControl.subviews[_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex].frame
```

**for Objective-C**

```
CGRect rect = _segmentedControl.subviews[_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex].frame
```